# Looking for a UPC Database to use with iOS

Tags: ios

Currently, I am trying to build an iOS app that uses the camera to scan a barcode off of a food item and display some basic information about that item along with a picture of the item. I am using the ZBar SDK to extract the UPC code from a barcode, and I am just looking for a simple way to get the information from the UPC code.

Does anyone know of a UPC product database that has a fairly simple way to interface with and feed data an iOS app given the UPC code? Ideally, I am looking for a free database hosted online that will also allow my app users to add to the database if their scanned product is not found.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Outpan Product Database](http://www.outpan.com)

- Millions of products indexed so far.
- Free for commercial/non-commercial use (CC BY-SA 3.0).
- Wiki-style version controlling for moderation and quality.

I started this database with developers in mind. I'm well aware of other databases that offer product data based on UPC/EAN barcode numbers, however none of them, in my opinion, have a developer-friendly license and/or are moderated properly for data quality. I have specifically tried to target these problems. 
Send the barcode number to the [Product API](http://www.outpan.com/developers.php) and get everything you need in JSON.

**Disclaimer: As you might have guessed I'm the founder of this project**